# reg.pushManager.subscribe is never fulfilled

Tags: javascript, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, web-push, web-notifications

I'm trying to enable web push notification but after call `reg.pushManager.subscribe` the promise is not resoved.

```
async enablePushNotification() { // CALLED ON USER CLICK
  try {
    const status = await Notification.requestPermission();
    if (status === 'granted') {
      const reg = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
      this.updateSubscriptionOnServer(reg);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error enabling push notification', error);
  }
}

async updateSubscriptionOnServer(reg) {
  try {
    const newSubscription = await reg.pushManager.subscribe({
      userVisibleOnly: true,
      applicationServerKey: urlB64ToUint8Array(VAPID_PUBLIC),
    });

    // BELLOW IS NEVER CALLED
    console.log('Subscription', newSubscription);
    const hasSubscription = !(newSubscription === null);
    this.setState(setHasSubscribed(hasSubscription));
    subscribeToPushNotification(newSubscription); // CALL API
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Ops', e);
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you get any error? I think this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775485/pushmanager-subscription-promise-never-fulfill-nor-reject) is related to your problem if I am not mistaken. And one of the answer give an idea that [Chromium team is working on the fix for this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=623062).

Comment: Any error, just didn't resolve the promise

Comment: I just tried this code in Chrome 65.0.3325.18 and it works. Only thing I had to correct was the missing? function keyword: async function enablePushNotification and async function  updateSubscriptionOnServer